# How to recover param in DialogFrament like popup

Tags: android, android-layout, popup, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to make a connection popup like in the man: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

The exemple like the man is done but now I can't recover the login and the password filled by the user.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtlogin"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/identifiant" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtpassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/motdepasse"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Class

```
    public class PopUpConnexion extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText login;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout


        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connexion, null))
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.connexion, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


// Here I want to recover the login and the password for sign in.


                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       PopUpConnexion.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });    
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

I try to recover the values ​​by all means but the object login of EditText type is always null.
Thanks

Edit:

```
    public class PopUpConnexion extends DialogFragment {

    EditText login;
    EditText password;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View textEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connexion, null);
        login  = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edtlogin); // with the debugger we can see it's the good EditText with the id
        login.setText("test"); // we can't see "test" in the EditText


        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connexion, null))
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.connexion, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            String tmp = "login: " + login.getText().toString() + "|"; // with the debugger we can see it's the good EditText with the id
                          Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), tmp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       PopUpConnexion.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });     
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

With login.setText("test"); we can conclude that the view who can see isn't the same that the view who I getText().

Final Edit:

```
    public class PopUpConnexion extends DialogFragment {

    EditText identifiant;
    EditText motdepasse;
    Button Connexion;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View textEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connexion, null);
        login = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edtlogin);
        password = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
        Connexion = (Button) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);


        Connexion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), login.getText() + " " + password.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setView(textEntryView);
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Finally I don't use the event manager like in the man.
I have already tested this technical but I have been some error because of the confussion beetween DialogFragment.OnClickListener and View.OnClickListener when you just write OnClickListener.
Now it's work, but I think that it exist an better method using the builder.setPositiveButon() & co.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want show dialog box frnd. that type you want

Comment: I don't understand what is "frnd" but I want do something link that: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/dialog_custom.png

Comment: ok you want just show popup means use          Dialog videoDialog = new Dialog(YouActivityname.this);
          videoDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          videoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.opecofabpopup);
          videoDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          videoDialog.show();

Comment: I already arrived to show the popup, I just want to recover the value of the EditText in the popup. I edit the first msg for show where I want the data.

Comment: the problem is that I never arrived to have login, login is always null : login = (EditText)(inflater.findViewById(R.id.edtlogin)); --> null
    / login = (EditText)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edtlogin); --> null
     / login = (EditText)this.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.edtlogin); -->null ; ...   But I just find somethings: final View textEntryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connexion, null);
        login = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edtlogin); --> it's not null but login.getText() return an empty string.

Comment: you can use textEntryView.login.gettext().try this brother.

Comment: textEntryView hasn't a method login

Comment: I find that new elements, I edit the first msg for put the next text at the end of the msg. I fact I get the good EditText but it's not the EditText who is on the popup.

Comment: Sorry for the time to edit and also sory for my english, it's not my cup of tea :p

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: I finally find the solution, I edit the first msg for put and explain the solution. Thanks.